# PDFBox IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line

Tags: java, selenium, pdfbox

I am trying check a specific text from a PDF that was loaded on page using PDFBox and Selenium but I am getting below error. I referred on this [[https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-testing-pdf-files/#:~:text=To%20handle%20a%20PDF%20document%20in%20Selenium%20test%20automation%2C%20we,the%20documents%2C%20and%20so%20on.]][1]

1. Method to verify for the pdf content

```
public void validate_view_of_pdf() {
        logger.info("View PDF method>>");
        
        
        String message = String.format("Close");
        logger.info("alert" + message);
        Assert.assertTrue(commonPage.clickOnMessagePrompt("span",message));     
        formsPage.clickViewExportPDFButton();       
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        logger.info("url >>" + url);
        
        try {
            
            String pdfContent = formsPage.readPdfContent(url);
            logger.info("pdfContent >>" + pdfContent);
            
            Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Performance Appraisal - Manager"));
            
        
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2. read PDF content

```
public String readPdfContent(String url) throws IOException {
        
        URL pdfUrl = new URL(url);
        InputStream in = pdfUrl.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(bf);
        int numberOfPages = getPageCount(doc);
        logger.info("The total number of pages "+numberOfPages);
        String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
        doc.close();
    
    return content;
        
    }
    
    public int getPageCount(PDDocument doc) {
        //get the total number of pages in the pdf document
        int pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages();
        return pageCount;
        
    }
```

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1103)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2589)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2560)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1222)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1122)
    at phr.pageobjects.FormsPage.readPdfContent(FormsPage.java:516)
    at phr.stepdefinitions.FormsStepDef.validate_view_of_pdf(FormsStepDef.java:464)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: please let me know if the url that has no .pdf extension has something to do with the error.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the `BufferedInputStream bf` into a file instead of feeding it to PDFBox? Could you open that file as a PDF file?

Comment: The error usually means the input is 0 bytes.